# How can i use built in membership methds with my own database ASP.NET mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, logging

Ok so i have been searching hard but i cannot find the solution to this problem, which should be fairly common though.

The problem is that ASP.NET MVC automatically creates the code using `WebSecurity` helper methods to log users in. Now what i want is connect that user and password database created by mvc with my own database so that i can write queries for example to identify which users have written which posts on a blog.

Please i need a little bit of guidance in this matter.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is to change the DefaultConnection connectionstring in your web.config file to point to your own database. The MVC security tables will then be created in your database. You can then link your table to these tables.

Comment: Ok. So when MVC creates these new tables in my database will they carry same attributes as they did in default database like passwords being salted or will i have to configure it too.

Comment: It will all be done as in the default database - as long as the database user credentials that you application is using has the correct permissions to create tables.